# Dataframe becomes larger than it should be after join operation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel dataframe which I am trying to populate with fields from other excel file like so:

```
df = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")
df_new = df.join(conv.set_index('id'), on='id', how='inner')
df_new['PersonalN'] = df_new['PersonalN'].apply(lambda x: "" if x==0 else x) # if id==0, its same as nan
df_new = df_new.dropna() # drop nan
df_new['PersonalN'] = df_new['PersonalN'].apply(lambda x: str(int(x))) # convert id to string
df_new = df_new.drop_duplicates() # drop duplicates, if any
```

it is clear that `df_new` should be a subset of `df`, however, when I run following code:
`len(df[df['id'].isin(df_new['id'].values)]) # length of this should be same as len(df_new)`

`len(df_new)`

I get different results (there are 6 more rows in `df_new` than in `df`). How can that be? I have checked all dataframes for duplicates and none of them contain any. Interestingly, following code does give expected results:
`len(df_new[df_new['id'].isin(df['id'].values)])`

`len(df_new)`

These both print same numbers

Edit:
I have also tried following: `others = df[~df['id'].isin(df_new['id'].values)]`, and checking if `others` has same length as `len(df) - len(df_new)`, but again, in dataframe `others` there are 6 more rows than expected

Comment: could you provide the problematic data?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without the data, but even if there are no duplicates in either of the dataframe, the size of the result of an inner join can be larger than the original dataframe size. Consider the following example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=["id_"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id_": list(range(10)) + [1] * 3, "something": range(13)})
df2.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
print(len(df1), len(df2))

==> 10 13

df_new = df1.join(df2.set_index("id_"), on = "id_")
len(df_new)
==> 13

print(df_new)
   id_  something
0    0          0
1    1          1
1    1         10
1    1         11
1    1         12
2    2          2
...
```

The reason is of course that the ids of the other dataframe are not unique, and a single id in the original dataframe (`df1` in my example) is joined to several rows on the other dataframe (`df2` in my example, `conv` in yours).

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your `conv` dataframe. Assume that your `df` that comes from file1 is

```
id PersonalN
0  1
```

And `conv` is

```
id other_col
0  'abc'
0  'def'
```

After the join you will get:

```
id PersonalN other_col
0  1         'abc'
0  1         'def'
```

size of `df_new` is larger than of `df` and `drop_dulicates()` or `dropna()` will not help you to reduce the shape of your resulting dataframe.